# create array using push method

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
 var members = [
     ['Fred G. Aandahl', '1951-1953', 'North Dakota'],
     ['Watkins Moorman Abbitt', '1948-1973', 'Virginia'],
 ];
```

I need to create like this dynamically, I am using the following code to do that:

```
var data = new array();
var members = [];
$.each(data, function (i, elem) {
    data.push(elem["p_age"], elem["p_name"], elem["p_date"]);
    members.push(data);
});
console.log(members);
}
```

I need to print this values, for that.

```
for(var x = 0; x < members.length; x++) {
    console.log(members[i][0]);
    console.log(members[i][1]);
    console.log(members[i][2]);
}
```

so when i try this i get following.

```
  [object][object][object][object][object][object]
```

Comment: var members = [
  ['Fred G. Aandahl', '1951-1953', 'North Dakota'],
  ['Watkins Moorman Abbitt', '1948-1973', 'Virginia'],
  ]; need to print the array like this. so i can use it further.

Comment: Your example starts with an empty array. Can you paste the actual code that creates `var data`?

Comment: Are you sure a multi-dimensional array like this is actually the best structure? An array of objects seems better suited to your problem.

Comment: How do you expect us to help you?  You're just adding elements to your array, but who knows what's in them as you didn't provide any of the code.  You're also not adding arrays to your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how is your code working! It has some error's if your already aware of.

Your code should work fine after you change to:-

```
var data = new Array();//Was an Error in your code
var members = [];
$.each(temp, function (i, elem) {
    data.push(elem["p_age"], elem["p_name"], elem["p_date"]);
    members.push(data);
});

console.log(members);
for (var x = 0; x < members.length; x++) {
    console.log(members[x][0]);//Was an Error in your code
    console.log(members[x][1]);
    console.log(members[x][2]);
}
```

Secondly, how does `data.push(elem["p_age"], elem["p_name"], elem["p_date"]);` works for you? It should give you `undefined`.

Just to get myself clear I wrote down your code to a fiddle. [Have a look.](http://jsfiddle.net/shubh0602/zMS8K/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var members=[];
$.each(data, function(i, elem) {
    members.push([elem["p_date"],elem["p_name"],elem["p_date"]]);
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(members))
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks suspect:

```
$.each(data, function(i, elem) {
  data.push(elem["p_date"],elem["p_name"],elem["p_date"]);
```

It looks like you're trying to iterate over `data`, pushing the elements back on to `data`. I imagine that the $.each() needs to iterate over something else.

I also question why you're pushing `elem['p_date']` onto an array twice.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is treating them as objects. Try using toString() method.

Answer (score 1):

Hi use `x` instead of `i` for loop.

```
for(var x=0;x<members.length;x++){
                      console.log(members[x][0]);
                      console.log(members[x][1]);
                       console.log(members[x][2]);
                 }
```

It will work.

Answer (score 1):

Not

```
var data=new array();
```

but

```
var data=new Array();
```

Array's class name is Array, but not 'array'.